# Update field in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get the following message via mqtt:

```
{"7801":{"teste":"teste888"}}
```

I need to get the information and update it in the `teste` field, like:

```
colection.update({
    "teste":"teste888"
})
```

How can I get this information straight from the string in JSON format?

My code:

```
//mqtt
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
client = mqtt.connect({
   host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
   port: 1883,
   username: 'xxxxxxx',
   password: 'xxxxxxxx'
});

// firestore
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./firestore/firestoreTeste.json');
admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = admin.firestore();

//client mqtt
client.on('connect', () => {
   let documents = db.collection('place2').get()
   .then(snapshot => {
       snapshot.forEach(doc => {
           var namePlace = [];
           namePlace = doc.id.toString();
           client.subscribe(namePlace + "/locker/testex/update")
           client.subscribe(namePlace + "/booking/testex/update")
       });
   });
  
});


client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
   console.log('JSON: ', message.toString());
   const namePlace = topic.split("/")[0];
   console.log("Name place: ", namePlace);
   const nameCol = topic.split("/")[1]
   console.log("Name colection: ", nameCol)
   const key = message.toString().substr(2,4);
   console.log("ID: ", key);
   const colection = db.collection("place2").doc(namePlace).collection(nameCol).doc(key);
   const teste = JSON.parse(message)
   console.log("teste: ", teste)
   colection.update({
       //teste
   })
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: More Information will help and Post full Firebase Code.

Comment: I post full firebase code, thank you

Comment: Great! .. You are Welcome .. When you post full code .. Developers can take a look and Find suitable Answer for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
colection.update({
  teste: teste["7801"]
})
```

This will take property `7801` from your JSON, and write that value to the `teste` field in the database.

If you don't know the name of the `7801` field, you can use a loop to get the values from all top-level properties:

```
let value = "";
Object.keys(teste).forEach((key) => {
  value += test[key];
});
colection.update({
  teste: value
})
```

Here I just concatenated the values, but you may want to do something more specific to your use-case.